# USB OTG as gadget in Linux - host doesn't detect peripheral

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to access the storage area of `rootfs` partition to a PC through `USB` Device Mode. 
My target is a`Marvell Kirkwood platorm`. I am using `Kernel 4.2.1`.

After booting up this image I load the g_mass_storage module:

```
modprobe g_mass_storage file=/dev/mmcblk0

Mass Storage Function, version: 2009/09/11
LUN: removable file: (no medium)
LUN: file: /dev/mmcblk0
Number of LUNs=1
g_mass_storage gadget: Mass Storage Gadget, version: 2009/09/11
g_mass_storage gadget: userspace failed to provide iSerialNumber
g_mass_storage gadget: g_mass_storage ready
```

This seems that it works fine. However it doesn't show any partition in the PC.
My PC doesn't detect target which is plugged by the `USB` cable and it doesn't give any output in `dmesg`

I am stuck with this `error`. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: The gadget driver is not enough. Does the periphereal controller driver work?

Comment: I enable Peripheral Controller in menuconfig, but how can I check if that works fine?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this platform, but you could check */proc/interrupts* to find if the interrupts count is increasing when you plug it into pc.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Now I see there is a problem with Peripheral Controller. I try use Marvell USB2.0 Device Controller, but I get a message: couldn't find an available UDC. However there is a file mv_udc.ko in /lib/modules/.. directory. Is it possible that my controller isn't probe properly?

Comment: did u figure out ur problem?  i'm stuck in a similar situation.  usb not detected in host.